# Difference between conditioned and conditioning variable?

Tags: conditional-probability, variable

Is there any technical difference between a `conditioned` and `conditioning` variable?

E.g. see below picture

[image]

Can I call both X and Y conditioned OR conditioning?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "technical difference"? After all, there is an obvious *prima facie* difference that most people would understand as being "technical": $X$ is the conditioning variable and $Y$ is not!  Please be aware, too, that this notation has at least two distinct uses (technically): they differ according to whether $(X,Y)$ is a random variable or $X$ is a parameter (and might not be random at all).  Which do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only difference lies in the grammar, like one is a past tense and the other is a continuous tense. So you would say "Y is *conditioned* on X" in this case. The word conditioning can be used in places like "You can find the expectation of Y by *conditioning* on X"

Comment: Conditioning is defined without any reference to time, so "past tense" is inapplicable.  "Continuous tense" makes no sense.  Is there perhaps a misspelling here?

Comment: Conditioning of-course is not defined with respect to time, but in English we change the tense in order to make sense. A similar case would be "Correlation" and "Correlated", we use both the words, depending on the tense, present and past respectively in this case.

Comment: I see that I misunderstood your meaning of "past tense."  Thank you for clarifying.  However, it isn't apparent this answers the question, which concerns some kind of (vaguely expressed) difference between $X$ and $Y$.  Are you asserting the variables play equivalent roles or not?